# Record audio on iPhone with smallest file size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file-upload, audio-recording

I want to record audio with iPhone and then upload it to server.

I could record the audio, but my question is about which format should I use to record audio, so that the Recorder will result a file with smallest file size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the results for few encoding supported by iPhone. Size of audio file in KB of duration 10 sec.

**kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC : 164**,

kAudioFormatAppleLossless : 430,

kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 : 475,

kAudioFormatULaw : 889,

kAudioFormatALaw : 889,

Among these **kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC** is having smallest size.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but what about iLBC (internet Low Bit Rate Codec), I heard that which is the smallest file size, did you try it? Thanks.

Comment: And maybe also interesting and relevant: AAC supports hardware-assisted encoding.

Comment: if i will user `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` or `kAudioFormatiLBC`, what is the extension type for the file when i saved it on the server ? .mp3 or what ?

Comment: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC - aac, and
kAudioFormatiLBC - amr

Comment: @JitendraSingh Thanks (Y)

Answer (score 3):

Apple iOS supports playback audio in these formats:

1. AAC (MPEG-4 Advanced Audio Coding)
2. ALAC (Apple Lossless)
3. HE-AAC (MPEG-4 High Efficiency AAC)
4. iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, another format for speech)
5. IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
6. Linear PCM (uncompressed, linear pulse code modulation)
7. MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3)
8. µ-law and a-law

For recording following formats are possible:

1. AAC (MPEG-4 Advanced Audio Coding)
2. ALAC (Apple Lossless)
3. iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, for speech)
4. IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
5. Linear PCM (uncompressed, linear pulse-code modulation)
6. µ-law and a-law

while only AAC supports hardware-assisted encoding (see [Apple iOS SDK documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html))

For the universality in availability I prefer MP3.

Check these links to find exact code to record audio - [**Recording Audio on an iPad with AVAudioRecorder**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPad_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28Xcode_4%29)

Comment: Can you please confirm that which iOS versions are supporting AMR (Adaptive Multi-rate) audio for recording and playback?

Comment: sorry, AMP is supported for playback only.

Comment: According to the following documentation, MP3 is not supported for recording, only playing. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6

Comment: This list is not up to date: see supported audio formats in the Apple iOS SDK Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of audio you are recording and the audio quality you want.

If for example, you are recording voice with the built in mic, iLBC will give you the smallest audio file (15.2 kbit/s for 20 ms frames, 13.33 kbit/s for 30 ms frames).