# How to reduce the avaudio recording file when recording for long time about an hour?

Tags: avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

***Description of problem:*** When i record an audio file for the time interval about 1 hours i get its **size around 600MB** so its to big I want that it should be compressed to les size but how i don`t know....? Reasong for doing compression is that ***it takes a lot of time in saving that file when i convert it to the NSData*** . SO please any  help or guide me through any how can get out from that problem.....:(

Any suggestion should be very appreciated...!

Thanks In Advance.....!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to choose correct format of encoding for reducing recorded audio file size.
Please see the link: [Record audio on iPhone with smallest file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279643/record-audio-on-iphone-with-smallest-file-size)

If still it is more than the expected size, then you can break file into multiple small chunks.
http://sspbond007.blogspot.in/2012/01/objective-c-filesplitter-and-joiner.html

Comment: thanku sir for giving me the idea of fileSplitter and joiner :)